# ListItem.Selected returning false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listbox with a list of items that get loaded when you navigate to a certain page. Then I have an on click that passes parameters to an AddProducts method. That method is what loops through all selected items and inserts values from the fields filled in as well as takes the values from the listItems and adds them as parameters to a stored procedure.

The problem I'm running into is that when looping through the listItems
if(selectedItem.Selected) is returning false, but in my method where I load the listbox I initialize a SelectedValue so I'm not sure why it's giving me the error message I have for no selected items. I was able to get it to work yesterday before I moved LoadListBoxCategories outside of LoadAddData but unsure as to why that would have any effect to if(listItem.Selected).

I'm relatively new to asp.net so any help/ explanation as to why my code isn't working is extremely appreciated. I've spent the last three days trying to figure this out and haven't found a solution that works.

Code:

Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session[IS_LOGGED_IN] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/utilities/companydata/login.aspx", true);
        return;
    }

    gvTextInputs.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(gvTextInputs_RowEditing);

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string pageId = Request.QueryString["pageid"];
        string productId = Request.QueryString["productid"];

        /* Add Mode */
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageId))
        {
            SetMode(MODE_ADD, "");
            LoadAddData(pageId);
            LoadListBoxCategories(pageId);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productId))
        {
            string imageServer;
            
            if (LoadProductData(productId, out imageServer))
            {
                InitImageGridview();
                InitTextGridview();
                InitStaticGridview();
                SetMode(MODE_EDIT, imageServer);
                SetImageServer(imageServer);
            }
            else
            {
                //TO DO - Return Error
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        InitImageGridview();
        InitTextGridview();
        InitStaticGridview();
    }
}
```

Load ListBox:

```
private void LoadListBoxCategories(string pageId)
{
    listBoxCategories.Visible = true;

    //This gets query is so I can store the CompanyId and the CombinedValue data from pageId
    string select = "SELECT companyName, cl.GbsCompanyId, cl.companyId, wpt.productTypeId, productName, (CAST(wp.pageId as varchar(200))  +'|'+ CAST(wp.productTypeId as varchar(200)) + '|' )  AS CombinedValue FROM CompanyList cl, WtpPages wp, WtpProductTypes wpt WHERE cl.companyId=wp.companyId AND wpt.productTypeId=wp.productTypeId AND wp.pageId=@pageId";

    SqlDataSource connectionId = new SqlDataSource(DB_CONNECT, select);
    connectionId.SelectParameters.Add("pageId", pageId);

    DataView dView = (DataView)connectionId.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    if (dView.Table.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        string companyId = dView.Table.Rows[0]["companyId"].ToString();
        string curCategoryProductTypeId = dView.Table.Rows[0]["CombinedValue"].ToString();
        // EXEC MCAdmin_GetAllCategoriesByCompanyId @companyId
        // Lists All Categories @companyId has Active
        string selectLoadData = "EXEC MCAdmin_GetAllCategoriesByCompanyId @companyId";

        SqlDataSource conn = new SqlDataSource(DB_CONNECT, selectLoadData);
        conn.SelectParameters.Add("companyId", companyId);

        lstCategoriesBox.Items.Clear();
        lstCategoriesBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", null));
        lstCategoriesBox.DataTextField = "productName";
        lstCategoriesBox.DataValueField = "CombinedValue";
        // Pre-selects the value of the productTypeId you are trying to add a product for
        // to send later run against a foreach insert in AddProduct()
        lstCategoriesBox.SelectedValue = curCategoryProductTypeId;
        testOutcomeCategory.InnerText = curCategoryProductTypeId;

        
        lstCategoriesBox.DataSource = conn;
        lstCategoriesBox.DataBind();
    
        
    }
}
```

AddProduct:

```
private string AddProduct(string companyId, out string errMsg)
{
    foreach (ListItem selectedItem in lstCategoriesBox.Items)
    {
        if (selectedItem.Selected)
        {
            // assign current productTypeId & pageId from selected Categories new CombinedValue column
            string[] splitColumnValue = selectedItem.Value.Split('|');

            string selectedPageId = splitColumnValue[0].ToString();
            string selectedProductTypeId = splitColumnValue[1].ToString();

            SqlDataSource connnection = new SqlDataSource(DB_CONNECT, "");
            connnection.InsertCommand = "EXEC MCAdmin_AddProductFromClassic @pageId, @productTypeId, @productCode, @imgDirectory, @numSides, @sortOrder, @isActive, @template, @template2, @template3, @EditorJson, @MockupTemplateBase, @MockupTemplateTreatment, @BorderDefault ";

            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("pageId", selectedPageId);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("productTypeId", selectedProductTypeId);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("productCode", txtProductCode.Text);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("numSides", ddlNumSides.SelectedValue);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("sortOrder", txtSortOrder.Text);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("isActive", ddlActive.SelectedValue);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("template", txtTemplate1.Text);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("template2", txtTemplate2.Text);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("template3", txtTemplate3.Text);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("EditorJson", txtJson.Text);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("MockupTemplateBase", txtMockupTemplateBase.Text);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("MockupTemplateTreatment", txtMockupTemplateTreatment.Text);
            connnection.InsertParameters.Add("BorderDefault", txtBorderDefault.Text);

            /* Special Product Code for Upload Artwork Business Card */
            if (txtProductCode.Text.ToUpper() == "BPFAH1-001-100")
            {
                connnection.InsertParameters.Add("imgDirectory", "/images/business-cards/general/");
            }
            else
            {
                connnection.InsertParameters.Add("imgDirectory", ddlImgDir.SelectedValue);
            }

            int result = connnection.Insert();

            if (result > 0)
            {
                SqlDataSource connect = new SqlDataSource(DB_CONNECT, "");
                connect.SelectCommand = "SELECT TOP 1 wtpProductId FROM WtpProducts ";
                connect.SelectCommand = "WHERE productTypeId=@productTypeId AND pageId=@pageId DESC ";

                connect.SelectParameters.Add("pageId", selectedPageId);  //
                connect.SelectParameters.Add("productTypeId", selectedProductTypeId); //

                DataView dView = (DataView)connect.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
                if (dView.Table.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    string wtpProductId = dView.Table.Rows[0]["wtpProductId"].ToString();
                    errMsg = "";
                    return wtpProductId;
                }
                else
                {
                    errMsg = "ERROR: Could not get productId of newly created Product.";
                    return "0";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errMsg = "ERROR: Could not add WtpProduct record to DB";
                return "0";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errMsg = "ERROR: You must select a Category";
            return "0";
        }
    }
    errMsg = "ERROR: Did not make it into the foreach loop";
    return "0";
}
```

OnClick method:

```
protected void OnClick_btnAddProduct(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pageId = Request.QueryString["pageid"];

    testOutcomeCategory.InnerText = lstCategoriesBox.SelectedValue; // This proves that I have something selected!!!

    string select = "SELECT companyName, cl.GbsCompanyId, cl.companyId, wpt.productTypeId, productName, baseImgDirectory, templateDirectory, wp.imageServer FROM CompanyList cl, WtpPages wp, WtpProductTypes wpt WHERE cl.companyId=wp.companyId AND wpt.productTypeId=wp.productTypeId AND wp.pageId=@pageId";

    SqlDataSource conn = new SqlDataSource(DB_CONNECT, select);
    conn.SelectParameters.Add("pageId", pageId);

    DataView dView = (DataView)conn.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    if(dView.Table.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        string companyId = dView.Table.Rows[0]["companyId"].ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageId))
        {
            string errMsg;
            string productId = AddProduct(companyId, out errMsg);
            if(productId != "0")
            {
                Response.Redirect("/utilities/companydata/add-edit-wtp-product.aspx?productid=" + productId, true);
                SetStatusMsg("Success", false);
            }
            else
            {
                SetStatusMsg(errMsg, true);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did the pageId change when you moved the code?

Comment: It did not change, I thought that yesterday but it was still the same. @jdweng

Comment: Is pageId a string or integer?

Comment: @jdweng it is a string

Comment: What are these doing? ````InitImageGridview(); InitTextGridview(); InitStaticGridview();```` If they are modifying the list, then that code is going to run before your button even click. Remember, Page_Load events will run first, then the button click event.

Comment: Those methods only handle HTML elements that don't have anything to do with the ListBox. @JohnPete22

Comment: It the 'I" in pageId lowercase or uppercase?  string pageId = Request.QueryString["pageid"];

Comment: Why do you have a ````!PostBack```` check inside your ````LoadListBoxCategories```` function? If you debug, is this function being called on postbacks? The function appears to only be called inside the ````!PostBack```` check on ````Page_Load```` but the additional logic check inside that function seems like it might be getting called elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry but this needs to be asked, have you stepped through the entire process with your debugger?

Comment: @mxmissile I have not figured out how to attach a debugger with an iisexpress host asp site

Comment: UPDATE: I just figured it out! So stupid but when I check if(selectedItem.Selected) since I'm looping through the ListBox items it starts at the first index of the ListBox and since the first isn't selected then that if goes to the else block. Remove the else and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I just figured it out! So stupid but when I check if(selectedItem.Selected) since I'm looping through the ListBox items it starts at the first index of the ListBox and since the first isn't selected then that if goes to the else block. Remove the else and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The list box instance is recreated on the server-side during the postback (as well as entire page). You do not set the selected items in the Page_Load event handler - `if (!IsPostBack)` goes to else branch. This is why you don't see them.

Comment: I know that `if (!IsPostBack)` doesn't ever go into the else because those methods being called simply make HTML elements visible and on every load, those HTML elements are not visible, on load and after the OnClick.
Also the ListBox SelectionMode is set to Multiple so even when I click multiple listItems I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

```
lstCategoriesBox.Items.Clear();
```

Ok, above goes nuclear - blows out the list, blows out the selection.

Ok, that's fine

```
    lstCategoriesBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", null));
    lstCategoriesBox.DataTextField = "productName";
    lstCategoriesBox.DataValueField = "CombinedValue";
```

Ok, above adds a new item. Should be ok, but one should setup the lb BEFORE adding any data - including that "--select--" row.

It just makes sense to "setup" the lb and THEN start adding data, right?
However,  But, if above works - ok, then lets keep going, but I would setup the lb before adding any rows of data. Say like this:

```
    lstCategoriesBox.DataTextField = "productName";
    lstCategoriesBox.DataValueField = "CombinedValue";
    lstCategoriesBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", null));
```

Now, the next line:

```
    lstCategoriesBox.SelectedValue = curCategoryProductTypeId;
```

Ouch! - we just cleared the lb, and now we trying to set it to a value? You can't do that - the lb just been cleared, right? You would need to load up the lb first, and THEN you can set it to the selected value, right?

I might be missing something here, but that lb needs to be loaded up with valid data BEFORE you attempt to set the selected value?

Comment: I think I'm following. So you're saying that because I have `lstCategoriesBox.Clear();` that when the OnClick fires, my list box gets cleared before any value is set? 
So if I remove the Clear() and rearrange the data to be loaded first before adding a new item, then `lstCategoriesBox.SelectedValue = curCategoryProductId;` can be set?

Comment: yes, you probably only want to ever load the lb one time, and only on first page load (isPostBack = false). but, yes, you look to be clearing the lb, and then attempting to set a value before it been loaded. I might not be following all the code, but that code just cleared the lb, and then we try to set it to a value - that can't work.

Comment: Okay, I removed the clear and rearranged the lb load so that the data gets added first before adding an item. Though I still get the same error when I click the button that calls AddProduct. I'll edit the post and add the OnClick method

Comment: I edited the original post. Hopefully that provides a little more info on what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

To test first, change following

```
Outcome Category.InnerText = list CategoriesBox.SelectedValue;
```

to

```
Category.InnerText = Request.Form["CategoriesBox-ClientID"]
```

If the data is coming in correctly, the list view cleared or reloaded when between reload and click events the page.

Comment: In `Form[""]` would I be putting the Form's ID or the ListBox's ID?

Comment: I tried both and nothing populated

Comment: No, in aspx form elements have another ID's like contentplaceholder1_ListBox1 you can get in html source code.

Comment: This is what I changed it too
`testOutcomeCategory.InnerText = Request.Form["listBoxCategories-ClientID"];`
And got nothing